# How do I grab all the html5 "data-" values from all selected input fields and create an object containing those values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some input boxes:

```
<input class="form" type="checkbox" name="item1" data-value="{ 'item1':'selected', 'price': 100 }" checked="checked">
<input class="form" type="checkbox" name="item2" data-value="{ 'item2':'selected', 'price': 300 }" checked="checked">
<input class="form" type="checkbox" name="item3" data-value="{ 'item3':'selected', 'price': 600 }">
<input class="form" type="text" name="text-input" data-value="Is there any way to have this value automatically equal to the .val() of whatever the user ends of inputting in the textbox?" >
```

I'd like to use JS / jQuery to grab all the `data-value` and put it all into an object for the input fields that are selected:

```
{
    item1 : {item1:'selected', price: 100},
    item2 : {item2:'selected', price: 300},
    text-input: "whatever the user put in"
}
```

Right now I use jQuery Serialize Object:

https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

But this only works for the `value=` attributes of input fields (works for radios, text, textarea, checkboxes). I don't think you can store a hash in the normal `value` attribute, so `data-` is going to be where I do it.

Something like:

```
var inputBoxContents = if ( [item is checked or selected] ) {
  $('.form').getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

Or maybe a pre-existing JS thing is available out there to use?

Comment: If you use jQuery, you should use `.data()` : http://api.jquery.com/data/ .

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2 : "Calling .data() with no parameters retrieves all of the values as a JavaScript object."

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the OP to include text inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.each()` to iterate over all the check box and grab the values that you need by using `.data()` function,

```
var xObj = {};

$(':checkbox.form:checked,:text.form').each(function(){
  xObj[this.attributes["name"].value] =
       ($(this).is(':checkbox'))? $(this).data('value'): this.value;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(xObj)); //{item1:{item1:'selected', price: 100}, ... }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GHc6j/1/)

Comment: Why mix raw JS and jQuery so much? Also, simply use a `:selected` selector added to your selector, rather than `if (this.checked)` in an `each`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Obviously, usage of pure js while picking up properties would improve the performance of the code.. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry just noticed, what were you talkin about.. :\

Comment: The question has changed now to include other input types. You may want to update your answer.

Comment: Re "`pure js while picking up properties would improve the performance`". I would argue that this code is likely run infrequently, probably only in response to a submit button, so saving microseconds/milliseconds is less important than code-size, portability and readability. I say *Make it fast where it actually has an impact, else focus on the other gains :)

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/85EK9/2/)

Try **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** function : This creates an array of values.

```
var inp = $('.form:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('value');
}).get();
```

Or If you need it in an object.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/85EK9/4/)

```
    var inp = {}; 
    $('.form:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        inp[this.name] = $(this).data('value');
    });
```

---

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/85EK9/6/)

**Update :**(With text inputs)

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var inp = {};
    $('.form').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checkbox') && this.checked) {
            inp[this.name] = $(this).data('value');
        } 
        if($(this).is(':text')){
            inp[this.name] = this.value;
        }
    });

    console.log(inp);
});
```

Comment: +1: Good use of map and the `:checked` selector. Much better answer (except they did specify *into an object*, not an array) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I thought about the same thing. updated now. map seems much better.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use the jQuery data() api to access the attributes. Which makes sure that if your data is in a JSON format that parses in to native js objects.

Alternatively if you are targeting the modern browsers -- IE11+, firefox, chrome and probably safari and Opera -- you can use the HTMLElement.dataset property that is available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

Of course this is probably what jQuery uses in browsers that support it and then polyfils gracefully for those that don't

Comment: Nice references, but not an *answer*. Can you provide a code example?